# Why did Frodo travel with the elves who were leaving Middle Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, hobbits

In the book *The Fellowship of the Ring*, the elves that Frodo, Pippin, and Sam meet on the road were High Elves leaving Middle Earth by way of the Grey Havens. Yet the Hobbits travel with them for a time. Isn't the Grey Havens on the other side of Hobbiton, and in the opposite direction from Rivendell? So wouldn't traveling with them back-tracking for the hobbits, or if the elves went with the hobbits wouldn't they be back-tracking?

This is the map at the beginning of the book:

[image]

This clearly shows that the hobbits traveled due east until they got to the Brandywine Bridge. They meet the elves halfway on the first segment of their journey, so wouldn't they be back-tracking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The elves were going to "the hill above Woodhall" and Woodhall is nearly due west of the Ferry. The road goes South from Hobbiton where it meets The East Road. The East Road goes nearly East and crosses the Brandywine Bridge.

See for instance: http://www.oocities.org/garfield1288/shire_map.jpg

(excerpt)

[image]

They run into the elves on or near the road that cuts through the trees in Woody End, somewhere close , but to the East of the branch. They took the "right branch to Woodhall" around "twilight."

They walked some, hid from the Black Rider, found the Elves, and walked some more to the Hill where the elves appeared to have a prepared place (a Grey-Haven Highway Authority Welcome Center)

The Hill was slightly North of the direct line to Buckland, but not really out of their way, considering the safety it afforded them.

EDIT:

Regarding the elves in question: they are not *on their way to* the Grey Havens. "We too are only tarrying here a while, ere we return over the Great Sea. But some of our kinsfolk still dwell in peace in Rivendell." They are living in the region and indications from the conversation are pretty clear that they were there even 17+ years prior when Bilbo left. At one point on the Hill in the evening, Gildor tells Frodo that he last said farewell to Bilbo on that very spot where they sat talking.

Gildor can easily be 1,000+ years old, so the exact duration of "a while" might mean something different to him than to you or me.

Comment: This seems to be a different map than the one I have. What edition of the Lord of the Rings did this come from?

Comment: According to ( http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/A_Part_of_the_Shire ) it is in FoTR immediately after the Prologue

Comment: How did they get down to that road you have marked? I found this map in my book, but it doesn't show anyway besides cross country. I was under the impression that they didn't go cross-country until after they meet the elves. They went cross-country right before Farmer Maggot's Farm.

Comment: Find the point in the book where they meet the elves and look backwards for clues. It may not all align perfectly, but the fork int he road left and right to The Yale/stock and Woodhall is certainly there. As a side note, there is no indication that I am aware of that Gildor's company came from Rivendel. He says they are wandering and tarrying a while before departing.

Comment: In fact, as I look at their meeting, there is much to indicate that they live in the region: they speak of when Biblo left (presumably the party, being 17+ years prior) and having seen Frodo and Bilbo often before.

Comment: So I went back and read carefully and it does appear that the hobbits went cross-country to get to the road you marked. It also seems that they meet the elves where you had marked, but wouldn't they still be back-tracking if they went back down the road with the elves? if They were trying to get to the woodhall.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, they were walking east, got to the fork at twilight, continued east, met the elves, walked furhter east and north of woodhall, talked and slept, then continued east to the ferry. They are making for Crickhollow which is in Buckland on the east side of the ferry.

Comment: @horatio I think he's saying that if the hobbits are walking east, and the elves are walking west, one of the two parties has to turn around to get to the encampment.  The probable answer is that the elves having already established camp were out for an afternoon/evening stroll.  Could they have been told to look for Frodo?

Comment: TGnat is right. If both companies are traveling towards their own destinations one of them has to turn around and head north to continue traveling.

Comment: I see. They are not *on their way to* the Grey Havens. "we too are only tarrying here a while, ere we return over the Great Sea. But some of our kinsfolk still dwell in peace in Rivendel." They are living in the region and indications from the conversation are pretty clear that they were their even 17+ years prior when Bilbo left. At one point on the Hill in the evening, Gildor tells Frodo that he last said farewell to Bilbo on that very spot where they sat talking.

Comment: But could this mean that he meet Bilbo when Bilbo was traveling to Rivendell after his Birthday Party and disappearance? Also if they were High Elves as Frodo said then they had been over the Sea and had returned. Finally, if the elves had been there 17+ years, why were the elves gone when Frodo woke up? would the elves send them off?

Comment: +1 for a shout out to the Grey Havens Highway Authority

Comment: @jacen.garriss Yes they met Bilbo after his their (Bilbo's and Frodo's) birthday party and Bilbo's joke (that contrary to the .. I have nothing nice to say about Jackson's films other than the visuals and the Elvish pronunciation being correct .. Frodo knew well about) and more or less in the same spot. I seem to recall that Gildor was actually one of the Elves to leave Middle-earth when Frodo goes. The add to the answe: Arwen gifted him the right; and Bilbo needed a companion there (so said Tolkien) and he was Ring-bearer; later Sam would go there - as would Legolas and Gimli!

Answer (score 5):

At this point in the book, the hobbits are not heading for Rivendell - they are simply heading for Frodo's new house in Crickhollow. They are in no great rush (even though Frodo aware of the Black Riders seeking him), and so would not be greatly perturbed at heading out of their way.

So, to answer your question of "Why?", I respond with "Why not?" - meeting the elves is a rare enough event that Pippin and Sam had never done it before, and I'm almost sure even Frodo hadn't either (although possibly once or twice with Bilbo). The elves were willing to have their company, and Frodo had questions about the world beyond the Shire, and about the Black Riders, which they could answer for him.

Comment: They are aware of the Black Riders. Frodo says a minute before meeting the elves that there was a Black Rider crawling towards them, but it ran away when it heard the elves. Sam also mentions a Black Rider asking after "Baggins" in Hobbiton.

Comment: Actually **Frodo had indeed met Elves before** and he even tells this to Pippin and Sam.